# Split string to max size of 30

Tags: arduino-c++

I need to write function that will split my large string into arr of max size 30. I tried something like this:

```
byte packetNumber;
String Text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";

void loop(){
  convertData(Text);
}

void convertData(String toSlice) {
  packetNumber = ceil((float)toSlice.length() / 30);
  byte mod = toSlice.length() % 30;
  char Arr[packetNumber][30];
  byte buf = 0, buf2 = 30;
  for (byte x = 0; x < packetNumber; x++) {
    for (byte y = buf; y < buf2; y++) {
      Arr[x][y] = toSlice[y];
      Serial.print(toSlice[y]);
      Serial.print("----->");
      Serial.print(y);
      Serial.print("\n");
    }
    if (x == packetNumber-2){
      buf+=mod;
      buf2+=mod;
    }
    else{
      buf+=30;
      buf2+=30;
    }
  }
  Serial.print(Arr[0]);
  Serial.print(Arr[1]);
  Serial.print(Arr[2]);
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.print(toSlice[32]);
  Serial.print("\nilosc pakietow: ");
  Serial.print(packetNumber);
  Serial.print("\n");
}
```

But the output is:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy te⸮⸮xt of the printing and typesetJ

I think it s because it takes too much memory because it overrides my other variables with this data. Do you know any good solution for this?

Comment: What is `String`? Is it a C++ string or a C string. You realize Arduino is using C++ yes? And yes, string handling, C++ libraries, floating point arithmetic etc will kill everything known as memory on an 8 bit MCU.

Comment: `Arr[packetNumber][30]` should be `Arr[packetNumber][31]` to contain the terminating `'\0'`

Comment: `toSlice.length()` clearly is C++.

Comment: Yes of course my mistake in the tag.